# How to Extend Application Class on Android with Angular nativeScriptBootstrap

Tags: java, android, angular, typescript, nativescript

> I'm trying to implement [OneSignal's Push Notification SDK](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-studio-sdk-installation#2-add-required-code) on android and in order to do so, I need to [Extend Application Class](http://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/advanced-topics/extend-application-activity#extending-application) and call `OneSignal.startInit` in the `onCreate` method.

I've been following the guides posted in the documentation and the `Android Extend Sample App`. Neither of these are working at all.

Trying to build the `Android Extend Sample App` results in `Java ID 0 not found` error.

I'm also exploring the possibility of `export class AppComponent extends android.app.Application` which I'm having no luck with so far.

Any tips would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this the later being the complicated one

Place the following in your main.ts

```
var application = require("application");
application.on(application.launchEvent, function (args) {
    if (args.android) {
        // For Android applications
    com.onesignal.OneSignal.startInit(application.android.context).init();
    } else if (args.ios !== undefined) {
        // For iOS applications, args.ios
    }
});
```

Create a new JavaScript file in your app folder - name it application.android.js

```
var application = require("application");
var superProto = android.app.Application.prototype;
var Application = android.app.Application.extend("org.myApp.Application", {
    onCreate: function () {
        superProto.onCreate.call(this);
        application.android.init(this);
        com.onesignal.OneSignal.startInit(this).init();
    }
});
```

Modify the application entry within the `AndroidManifest.xml` file found in the `<application-name>app/App_Resources/Android/` folder

```
<application
        android:name="org.myApp.Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: The first option worked best for my application. Thank you so much!